# error while looping in list of object in apex

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, controller

Im currently sending a list of jS object from my lightning helper class to my apex controller. In my controller the class is define like this :

```
@AuraEnabled
public static map<String,Object> upsertEtapes(list<Object> etapes, String dossierId){
    system.debug('## starting method upsertEtapes');

    map<String,Object> mapOfResult = new map<String,Object>();
    list<Etapes_du_dossier__c> listOfUpdates = new list<Etapes_du_dossier__c>();
    list<Etapes_du_dossier__c> listOfInserts = new list<Etapes_du_dossier__c>();
    system.debug('## list of object : '+ etapes);

    for(Object obj : etapes){ ...}

}
```

when i debug my etapes I get this :

> ({id=a017E000004hEdvQAE, updated=true, name=Mise en bière, dateheure=2017-06-01T10:00:00.000Z, lieu=test cimetière, lieuId=0017E00000XYWYmQAP, commentaires=null},   {id=a017E000004hEdwQAE, updated=true, name=Levée de corps, dateheure=2017-07-06T22:00:00.000Z, lieu=null, lieuId=null, commentaires=null})

Which mean that my lightning is sending the right info. But in apex salesforce is not able to process the list. When I'm trying to access `etapes[0]`. Salesforce crash with an internal error.

The list is visibly not empty and is an instance of a `list<object>`. So how come that i can't access `etapes[0]` nor loop over that list ?

The error in the log is an internal error with an unusable id.

What could I have done wrong, and what check am I missing?

Comment: I think we are missing relevant code here

Answer (score 2):

Lightning sometimes has trouble sending complex data types to the server, and perhaps the accents in the string have caused trouble with it's serialization.

If you are completely stuck, on the Javascript side, stringify the list:

```
var etapesListe = JSON.stringify(etapes);
//send this instead of the array of objects
```

In the controller, change the parameter to accept a String

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String,Object> upsertEtapes(String etapesListe, String dossierId){
```

Finally, deserialize the string into your `sObject`:

```
Etapes_du_dossier__c[] allEtapes = (Etapes_du_dossier__c[])JSON.deserialize(etapesListe,Etapes_du_dossier__c[].class);
```

You should then be able to iterate as required - although don't forget, your iterator var is now a typed `Etapes_du_dossier__c` not and `Object`